# How I authentificate my android app requests to my server?

Tags: java, android, security, serve

I have an Android app that connects to a external server for receiving/setting data. The problem that the server reply to request of everyone. How can I make it reply only from the request of my application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Server/box reply (or) application reply? You can't stop server/box reply if the port is open. Application reply, you can use different techniques like 1) special tokens 2) Registered users etc.,

Comment: I want the server reply only for my application request !! Thanks in advance

Comment: Then better move this question to network/Super user site, not related to Java/Android.

Comment: okey thanks for help I'm going to post it now !!

Comment: You could add a salt&peppered token to the end of the ur.

Comment: could you explain that please ?